# Replace CSS transition height with transition scale

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am trying to replace my CSS transition(height) with a scale transition for improved performance. This is what I have got:

```
#primaryNav {
    height: auto;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.nav-small {
    transform: scale(1,0.5); 
}
```

Now this works really well but the children elements inside .nav-small are also scaling which is a pain - any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `scale` would technically scale itself and everything inside it. the only option I can think of is to apply `scale` to children as well, so that when you are _scaling in_ the parent, you have to _scale out_ the children in proportion. but I am not sure if this is a good idea in your case as there is a possibility that it may introduce unwanted results (such as blurring of text within children elements). can you share a fiddle please?

Comment: Did my solution ever end up working out for you?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `transform`, try using `clip`, which should net you similar performance to `transform` in modern browsers. The `clip` CSS rule works by defining a box that effectively chops off a portion of the element it is applied to.

From [css triggers](http://csstriggers.com/), we can see that changes in `height` trigger an expensive reflow, repaint, and composite, which is what was likely causing your performance problems. Like changes in `transform`, changes in `clip` don't trigger any of these costly browser events. In summary, `clip` (much like `transform`) is faster/lighter on browser resources than `height`, so this may give you the performance boost you're looking for.

To update your existing code, you can use the following:

```
#primaryNav {
    height: 100px;
    transition: clip 0.5s;
    clip: rect(0px, 0px, 100px, 0);
}

.nav-small {
    clip: rect(0px, 0px, 50px, 0);
}
```

The only downside is that you need to know the original height of your nav  (or get it using JavaScript) so you can set the initial value for `clip`.